# Google Cloud AppEngine Java Code Recurring Components Update for every run

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My AppEngine standard version Java code(maven) is getting components updated whenever I say appengine:run, though Components are up to date. Found that "appengine-maven-plugin" dependency causes the problem for this auto components update. Whenever I say "appengine-maven-plugin" version 1.3.1 then I don't have any problem, but If I use the latest version 2.2.0 then components are getting updated every time.

Appreciate if someone help me to solve this issue

Using below log we can see the components are getting updated

```
C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo>mvn clean install appengine:run [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building helloworld 1.0-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ helloworld --- [INFO] Deleting C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ helloworld
--- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\src\main\resources [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ helloworld --- [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] Compiling 8 source files to C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\classes [WARNING] /C:/Lourdu/Development/ACT/SVN_Latest/demo/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/java8/Utilities/Utilities.java: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. [WARNING] /C:/Lourdu/Development/ACT/SVN_Latest/demo/src/main/java/com/example/appengine/java8/Utilities/Utilities.java: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ helloworld --- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\src\test\resources [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ helloworld --- [INFO] No sources to compile [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ helloworld --- [INFO] No tests to run. [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ helloworld --- [INFO] Packaging webapp [INFO] Assembling webapp [helloworld] in [C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT] [INFO] Processing war project [INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\src\main\webapp] [INFO] Webapp assembled in [67657 msecs] [INFO] Building war: C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war [INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ helloworld --- [INFO] Installing C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\lourdurajan_george\.m2\repository\com\example\appengine-j8\helloworld\1.0-SNAPSHOT\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war [INFO] Installing C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\pom.xml to C:\Users\lourdurajan_george\.m2\repository\com\example\appengine-j8\helloworld\1.0-SNAPSHOT\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom [INFO] [INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:2.2.0:run (default-cli) @ helloworld ---



Your current Cloud SDK version is: 303.0.0 Installing components from version: 303.0.0

+---------------------------------------------------+ |        These components will be installed.        |
+------------------------------+---------+----------+ |             Name             | Version |   Size   |
+------------------------------+---------+----------+ | Cloud Datastore Emulator     |   2.1.0 | 18.4 MiB | | gRPC python library    |  1.20.0 |  1.5 MiB | | gRPC python library          |  1.20.0 |      | | gcloud app Java Extensions   |  1.9.81 | 61.0 MiB | | gcloud app Python Extensions |  1.9.91 |  6.1 MiB |
+------------------------------+---------+----------+

For the latest full release notes, please visit:   https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes

#============================================================#
#= Creating update staging area                             =#
#============================================================#
```

Below log says, even if we try to deploy the code with appengine-maven-plugin version 1.3.2, finally we have got error Cloud SDK mismatch error.

```
INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) @ helloworld ---
[INFO] Staging the application to: C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine standard environment application.
Aug 06, 2020 12:11:13 AM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFO: submitting command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre\bin\java.exe -cp C:\Users\lourdurajan_george\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg --disable_update_check --enable_jar_splitting stage C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\helloworld-1.0-SNAPSHOT C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] GCLOUD: Reading application configuration data...
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2020-08-06 00:11:20.417:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4363ms
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD:
[INFO] GCLOUD: Beginning interaction for module rbr_dev...
[INFO] GCLOUD: 0% Scanning for jsp files.
[INFO] GCLOUD: 0% Compiling jsp files.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:07 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:11 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/index.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:11 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/shared/_headerIncludes.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:12 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/authenticationError.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:12 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/home.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:12 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/shared/_footer.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:12 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC processFile
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Built File: /views/shared/_header.jsp
[INFO] GCLOUD: Aug 06, 2020 12:12:12 AM org.apache.jasper.JspC execute
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Generation completed with [0] errors in [4793] milliseconds
[INFO] GCLOUD: Success.
[INFO] GCLOUD: Temporary staging for module rbr_dev directory left in C:\Lourdu\Development\ACT\SVN_Latest\demo\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:36 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-08-06T00:12:18+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/86M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy (default-cli) on project helloworld: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:deploy failed: Cloud SDK versions before 171.0.0 are not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Comment: How did you determine that up-to-date components are getting updated? A sample of the code resulting in such behavior would be appreciated, for error reproduction purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited and updated the logs in the original questions. Basically if you see it, the current SDK and installing components are the same (303.0.0). This is happening whenever I say appengine:run or appengine:deploy. This comes only with  "appengine-maven-plugin" version 2.2.0. I am not sure why it is happening now. Please let me know if there are any settings I missed at code level.

Comment: If you think this is a problem with the latest version of Maven, you should report this issue separately in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), where it gets assessed, and fixed in accordance with its level of urgency.